# Visual Studio for Mac 2022 - Where is GIT and Version Control?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-mac

I am bit new to this Visual Studio for Mac 2022 as it came out just recently for Mac OS.
I am learning by following a video course, which is done on Windows. And there is supposed to be an option to "Add to Source Control" or from the official docs for Visual Studio for Mac => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/working-with-git?view=vsmac-2019 there is supposed to be a tab "Version Control" to push my project to my Github.

But there is not. If i try to go like this:

1. Select Solution
2. Commit or Stash
3. Push
   i get error "Create an initial commit first"

But i can not commit as this i the only way to commit. It is bit frustrating.
Also there is no way to connect my Github account to the VSforMac 2022 even if I use the "Help" and put in Git or Github this it the only option that it finds.

Did they just forgot to add Git integration to the new Visual Studio code for 2022 ? Or I am missing something in settings or possible a package?

See screenshot https://ibb.co/N2nPMbg
PS: I have Git installed on my machine

Thanks!

Comment: Please post some screenshots of what you're seeing.

Comment: You could just use git from command line. Its way faster and in my opinion easier to use

Answer (score 1):

They have updated the documentation now to match the new menu options in Visual Studio 2022 for Mac now.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/mac/working-with-git?view=vsmac-2022

Answer (score 0):

Did You try - publish new project step:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/mac/set-up-git-repository?view=vsmac-2022#publishing-a-new-project

Maybe You can also try key:
"Navigate to (Quick Launch on Windows) ⌘"
and type: git or version control and see if there is related action,
or see in settings if there is a shortcut to version control tab/window.

Comment: HI, thanks for the link. I went this way and create Blank solution and ticked " Use git for version control" but still i dont have a "Version control" avalible in the menu https://ibb.co/N2nPMbg

Comment: I see you have "Git" tab it should be it. Between 'View, Search' and 'Project, Build'. Top bar.